# Choosing time from 2300-0000 for different days

Tags: python, date, datetime, time

So I'm having a issue with with the 23:00-00:00 time for different days within in Python.

```
times                      A    B         C          D
2003-01-08 00:00:00       NaN  0.086215  0.086135  0.090659
2003-01-08 23:00:00       NaN  0.060930  0.059008  0.057293   
2003-01-09 23:00:00       NaN  0.102374  0.101441  0.100743   
2003-01-10 00:00:00       NaN  0.078799  0.077739  0.076138   
2003-01-10 23:00:00       NaN  0.207653  0.205911  0.202886   
2003-01-11 00:00:00       NaN  0.203436  0.201588  0.197515  
...
```

What I'm looking for is to mainly select the `00:00:00` hour which is why I've applied `df = df.reset_index().groupby(df.index.date).first().set_index('times')` but if that doesn't exist that it should use the `23:00:00` of the previous days as the `00:00:00` of the next day. The following is wrong:

```
times                     A     B         C         D
2003-01-08 00:00:00       NaN  0.086215  0.086135  0.090659  
2003-01-09 23:00:00       NaN  0.102374  0.101441  0.100743   
2003-01-10 00:00:00       NaN  0.078799  0.077739  0.076138    
2003-01-11 00:00:00       NaN  0.203436  0.201588  0.197515
...
```

How do I get it to look at the `23:00:00` of the previous day to the `00:00:00` of the next day, to achieve this solution.

```
2003-01-08 00:00:00       NaN  0.086215  0.086135  0.090659
2003-01-08 23:00:00       NaN  0.060930  0.059008  0.057293
2003-01-10 00:00:00       NaN  0.078799  0.077739  0.076138   
2003-01-11 00:00:00       NaN  0.203436  0.201588  0.197515
...
```

Comment: What class is `df` in your code?

Comment: Unsure, when I use the help it prints this                                                   `help(df)
Help on DataFrame in module pandas.core.frame object:

class DataFrame(pandas.core.generic.NDFrame)`